# Make RegionFunction Invisible

Tags: plotting

I'm using a RegionFunction like in the example below, and in the past, and in the Mathematica documentation (from where the code is copied, ContourPlot3D>Options>BoundaryStyle), the RegionFunction is not visible. But when I run this in my Mathematica, it is, and I can't figure out how to make it vanish. See print screens for comparison.

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None,  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, w}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4]]
```

[image: My Plot]
[image: Example in Documentation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`.

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! That fixes it. Is the example code in the documentation old, or any idea why it does not provide the same result?

Comment: I don't know how often (or when) WRI reevaluates the examples in the documentation. But yes, it looks like the output of this particular example has not been updated (this should probably have happened in 12.1 when ``RegionBoundaryStyle`` was added).